# Selectize dropdown is not moved with input on scrolling the parent div

Tags: angular, scroll, dropdown, selectize.js

I am using selectize plugin in angular for dropdowns that are displaying within a scrollable div, on scrolling the div when a dropdown was opened, the position of the dropdown is fixed and not moving up/down along with the selectize Input on scrolling. I want it to move with the Input on scroll. Is there a way to achieve this?

The position is set to absolute for both Input and dropdown in the selectize css.

Comment: please share the code, if possible a stackblitz in the question! also the expected output!